# How do I change the color of the captcha text?

Tags: php, yii2

I am using the default captcha `yii\captcha\Captcha` in the default contact form as below:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(yii\captcha\Captcha::className(), [
    'template' => '
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div>
        </div>',
])?>
```

How do I change the color of the text from the default blue to `#a2915d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color is determined by [`foreColor`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-captcha-captchaaction.html#$foreColor-detail) for `yii\captcha\CaptchaAction`. `foreColor` expects an integer so you have to pass the color code as **a hexadecimal or decimal literal**.

In your controller, you can edit `actions()` to pass `foreColor`:

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        ...
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'foreColor' => 0xA2915D // or 10654045 if you want the decimal value
        ],
    ];
}
```